# Change function to be called only once

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I use a chrome extension for redirect links and i want the redirection to be 
  one time executed for each sesion of browser.
  I'm a beginner ,i tried to change the code but i can't stop the function to 
  run endlessly,

```
 function matchUrl(url) {
   if (rules == undefined || url == undefined) {
    return false;
 }
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
var isEnabled = rules[i].isEnabled;
var isRegex = rules[i].isRegex;
var src = rules[i].src;
var dst = rules[i].dst;
if (isEnabled) {
  if (isRegex) {
    var re = new RegExp(src);
    if (url.search(re) != -1) {
      newUrl = url.replace(re, dst);
      return newUrl;
    }
  } else {
    if (url == src) {
      return dst;
    }
  }
}
```

}

return false;
}

Comment: Are you editing an existing chrome extension?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want so the posted code may be unrelated and you probably need to unregister the navigation listener completely instead, look for chrome.webNavigation or chrome.webRequest or chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: Yes ,i try to edit an existing extension, https://urlautoredirector.github.io/

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, change, tab) {
  if (change.status == "loading") {
    newUrl = matchUrl(change.url);
    if (newUrl) {
      console.log("Match:" + change.url)
      console.log("Target:" + newUrl)
      if (isNewTab == false) {
        lastTabId = tabId;
        chrome.tabs.update({url: newUrl});
      } else {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: newUrl}, function(tab){
          notify();
        });
      }
    }
  }
  if (change.status == "complete" && tabId == lastTabId) {
    notify();
    lastTabId = 0;
  }
});

Comment: I have to change something here? Excuse me, but I don't know much about programming.

Comment: Can anyone help me, for a week i am looking for a solution